# What is this part in my laptop screen?

Tags: network-adapter, hardware-detection

So recently the hinges of my laptop broke, and while fixing it I came across the following component.

[image: component]

My laptop is an Asus VivoBook [S551LB-CJ046H](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/S551LA/E_eManual_S551LA_LB_VER8134.pdf). It's at the bottom of my screen, and is normally hidden by a cover. I think that it is part of the Wi-Fi antenna. Initially there were two cables leading to it, however one of the cables has broken. Surprisingly my Wi-Fi is still working fine. Taking the component off of the screen there are two small metallic blocks that come in contact with the screen backcover.

This has generated two questions:

- Am I right in assuming that it is part of the Wi-Fi module?
- What would happen if I disconnected the remaining cable from this component?
  Would it diminish the signal significantly?

Comment: What color was the second one?

Comment: I couldn't make out much from your pic, but very often a laptop will have multiple antennas for WIFI (to handle differential signaling/mimo/corridors and/or multiple bands). It can still work with degraded performance - which could be invisible save that it's slower/less sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "metallic blocks" you describe are the Wi-Fi antennas. The cables connect them to the wireless adapter located in the laptop base.

On many laptops, the Wi-Fi antenna is located above or below the display. Systems with all-metal chassis often have a visible "antenna line" similar to what you might see on a metal smartphone to allow signals through; if such a line is present, that's where the actual antennas are located. That cable connects the wireless network adapter (often a small M.2 card, type 2230, with older systems typically using mPCIe) to an antenna. This is what an antenna line may look like on a laptop:

[image: Antenna line on HP ENVY x360 laptop]

If you have two antenna cables, disconnecting one of them will reduce signal strength and range, and limit your Wi-Fi to single-stream, or 1x1, operation (most better laptops have dual-stream or 2x2 Wi-Fi). If the other cable is disconnected, you'll lose all wireless connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi module, no: [WiFi antenna](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1229&bih=578&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=cuIOXNSaDqaH0gKM4YKYCA&q=WiFi+antenna+in+laptop), yes. That's one of the two antennas commonly found on the back of laptop screens, which run to snap-on connectors on the WiFi Module. The module looks at signal from both and uses the better one. Don't disconnect the other, else WiFi reception will greatly suffer.

Answer (score 0):

This laptop is similar to yours https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=w95gpUxIp7Y.

It also has two wires, One White and one Black, They are both connected to the Wifi adapter card.

Like Davidgo said, Your wifi might still work, but with a loss of range or speed. Some Wifi cards are different, but normally they use two antennas (I believe 3 usually means 5GHz).

One to send and one to receive (Pretty much 2x faster than having it share one antenna to send and receive), I guess the Adapter knows its missing one and switches to 1 radio (Obviously slower).

You might find this interesting https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-you-exchange-the-black-and-white-antenna-cables-main-and-aux-that-attach-to-the-WiFi-adapter-card-in-laptops

Answer (score 0):

You would be right assuming that it is a wifi antenna. My old HP 2000-299wm laptop is very similar, except my laptop's antenna runs to the top of the screen.